# Rails association trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have 3 Objects: a `Player`, `Team` and a `User`.

```rb
# user.rb
has_one :player, dependent: :destroy
has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
```

```rb
# team.rb
belongs_to :user
```

```rb
# player.rb
belongs_to :user
```

My problem is between the associations for `player` and `team`:

- a Team should have many and belong to many players
- a Player should have many and belong to many teams

So that I can access them via `player.teams` or `teams.players`

Further on, I need to add/remove players to teams in the future, so basically adding the connection (Join Table).

What is the best approach for this? What is the create Action on the `TeamsController` looking like.

### Use Case

- A lot of `Player` register
- One `Player` creates a `Team`
- A `Team` consists of 8 `Players`
- So more `Players` will be added in the future from the Owner

and here is the problem, how do I handle that connection between `Players` and `Teams`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the use case, one cannot tell if you have defined the associations correctly. So there is no way I can suggest the best approach. What is the use case? What does the view look like?

Comment: Well I don't have the associations defined at all :) That's my problem, for I seek help. I updated my Question with the Use case.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldnt you just try has_and_belongs_to_many association?

UPDATE:

1. First you have to create a join table:

   ```
   class CreatePlayersTeamsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
       create_table :players_teams, id: false do |t|
         t.integer :player_id
         t.integer :team_id
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Then you define associations
   player.rb :
   `has_and_belongs_to_many :teams`
   team.rb :
   `has_and_belongs_to_many :players`
3. In your TeamsController I'd use nested attributes and pass player_ids from the view

Hope it helps

Comment: That's not an answer Bajena, but with exactly that I need help.